# How to prove that $\tan\frac{B-C}{2}=\frac{b-c}{b+c}\cot\frac{A}{2}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have read these formulae in my book but i could not understand how these are proved.
**Napier's Analogy-Tangent's Rule:**
$\tan\frac{B-C}{2}=\frac{b-c}{b+c}\cot\frac{A}{2}$
$\tan\frac{C-A}{2}=\frac{c-a}{c+a}\cot\frac{B}{2}$
$\tan\frac{A-B}{2}=\frac{a-b}{a+b}\cot\frac{C}{2}$
where $A,B,C$ are the angles of a triangle ABC and $a,b,c$ are the sides opposite to the angles $A,B,C$ respectively.

---

In proving $\tan\frac{B-C}{2}=\frac{b-c}{b+c}\cot\frac{A}{2}$, I only know that the formula for the $\cot\frac{A}{2}=\sqrt{\frac{s(s-a)}{(s-b)(s-c)}}$ and i do not see any method to prove this identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We have to use the fact that in a triangle ABC we have

$$\frac{\cos (\frac{B+C}{2}) \sin (\frac{B-C}{2})}{\sin (\frac{B+C}{2})\cos(\frac{B-C}{2})}=\frac{\sin B−\sin C}
{\sin B+\sin C} =\frac{b−c}
{b+c}$$

The full proof can be found [here](http://www.math-only-math.com/law-of-tangents.html).